# How to make a mysql realtime database with flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, real-time

I am working on this chat app and I obviously don't have any idea how to do this but I have donr the basics such as I made the connection between my app and the mysql db and fetch the data but I think that I will need to make the db a real-time db which again I have no idea how to do so any help with that part ?
also new to flutter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets use this tutorial. Also look into the concept of sockets. Keep in mind when you making a chat application you should also take into account privacy and security.

> 1. Connect to a WebSocket server.
>
>    The web_socket_channel package provides the tools you need to connect to a WebSocket server. The package provides a WebSocketChannel
>    that allows you to both listen for messages from the server and push
>    messages to the server.
>
>    In Flutter, use the following line to create a WebSocketChannel that connects to a server:
>
>    ```
>    final channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
>      Uri.parse('wss://echo.websocket.org'),
>    );
>    ```
> 2. Listen for messages from the server.
>
>    Now that you've established a connection, listen to messages from the server. After sending a message to the test server, it sends the
>    same message back. In this example, use a `StreamBuilder` widget to
>    listen for new messages, and a Text widget to display them.
>
>    ```
>    StreamBuilder(
>      stream: channel.stream,
>      builder: (context, snapshot) {
>        return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
>      },    
>    )
>    ```
> 3. Send data to the server.
>
>    To send data to the server, `add()` messages to the sink provided by the WebSocketChannel.
>
>    ```
>    channel.sink.add('Hello!');
>    ```
> 4. Close the WebSocket connection.
>
>    After you're done using the WebSocket, close the connection:
>
>    ```
>    channel.sink.close();
>    ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Askless](https://github.com/WiseTap/askless-js-client), it simplifies the creation of real-time Flutter Apps using any database

I developed this package with the goal of simplifying the websocket usage. The library will automatically send again the data to the server if the client loses a connection, also [it has other benefits](https://github.com/WiseTap/askless-flutter-client#askless---flutter-client). The [Askless server side](https://github.com/WiseTap/askless) needs to be coded in JavaScript/TypeScript.

The Flutter Client will be able to listen to real-time updates using MySQL or other databases, like:

```
//other widgets...

AsklessClient.instance
    .listenAndBuild(
      route: 'allProducts',
      builder: (context,  snapshot) {
          if(!snapshot.hasData)
             return Container();

          final listOfProductsNames =
              (snapshot.data as List)
              .map((product) => Text(product['name'])).toList();

          return Column(
             children: listOfProductsNames,
          );
      }
    ),

//other widgets...
```

It also has a [JavaScript/TypeScript](https://github.com/WiseTap/askless-js-client) client support that can be paired with Flutter if, for example, there is a web version of your App using React or other SPA framework.